# Convert JSON in comma separated string with nested array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json, string

I know there are a lot of examples out there, but still I can't get it working. I have a JSON like this:

```
{"domiciles":[{"country":"AF"},{"country":"AX"},{"country":"AL"}],"investor":[{"type":"ii"},{"type":"pi"}]}
```

stored in sessionStorage.getItem("profile");

How can I convert in two comma seperated strings? Like ...

```
AF,AX,AL
ii,pi
```

Failed attempts:

```
var dataResidence = sessionStorage.getItem("profile");
var resultResidence = dataResidence.map(function(val) {
  return val.country;
}).join(',');
console.log(resultResidence);
```

Or:

```
var newString = "";
for(var i=0; i< dataResidence.domiciles.length;i++){
    newString += userDefinedSeries.country[i];
    newString += ",";
}
console.log(newString);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to parse the string you get from the `sessionStorage`, then you can map and join:

```js
var profile = '{"domiciles":[{"country":"AF"},{"country":"AX"},{"country":"AL"}],"investor":[{"type":"ii"},{"type":"pi"}]}'; // sessionStorage.getItem("profile");

var dataResidence = JSON.parse(profile);

function mapAndJoin(arr, key) {
  return arr.map(function(o) {
    return o[key];
  }).join();
}

var domiciles = mapAndJoin(dataResidence.domiciles, 'country');

var investor = mapAndJoin(dataResidence.investor, 'type');

console.log(domiciles);

console.log(investor);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help on this! I was wandering ... I also saw your first version (without mapAndJoin()) ... is doing it via a general function like mapAndJoin() just better practice in case of multiple outputs ... or are there even further pro arguments?

Comment: It's the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself) - don't repeat yourself. If you have several cases that use the same code, abstract it to a method. Now if I want to change the separator from a comma to a slash, I can change it in one place. In addition, handling new cases is very easy, just call the method again with different params. I can also test the abstraction, to ensure that it handles edge cases, such as empty arrays, non arrays, key not found, etc...

Comment: Good to know ... thanks for the additional information!

Answer (score 1):

One way of doing it

```js
var obj={"domiciles":[{"country":"AF"},{"country":"AX"},{"country":"AL"}],"investor":[{"type":"ii"},{"type":"pi"}]};
console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
var countries = obj.domiciles;
var str = '';
for(i=0;i<countries.length;i++){
if(i != countries.length - 1)
str+= countries[i].country+",";
else
str += countries[i].country;
}
console.log(str);

var type = obj.investor;
var str1 = '';
for(i=0;i<type.length;i++){
if(i != type.length - 1)
str1 += type[i].type+",";
else
str1 += type[i].type;
}
console.log(str1);
```